# Error 91 creating Shell Application when Option Explicit added

Tags: excel, vba

This function gets arguments and unzip a zip file.

Code in "Module1" calls my function code that is in "Module2".

```
Call Module2.UnzipAFile(ZipPath, UnzippedPath, File.Name)
```

It was working until I used `Option Explicit` and `Dim`ed my variables in Module1 (had to split the code because it was long).

Now I get Error 91 on

```
 ShellApp.Namespace(tempUnzip_FolderPath).CopyHere ShellApp.Namespace(zippedFileFullName).Items      'by A-Z it goes file by file doing an Extact to a specific folder called "tempUnzip"
```

[image]

```vb
Sub UnzipAFile(zippedFileFullName As Variant, unzipToPath As Variant, Overwrite As String)

    Dim ShellApp As Object
    Dim OLD_NAME As String
    Dim NEW_NAME As String
    
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    
    ArchiveLastOccuranceofPoint = InStrRev(Overwrite, ".")
    ArchiveFileExtension = Right(Overwrite, Len(Overwrite) - ArchiveLastOccuranceofPoint)
    ArchiveFileNoExtension = Replace(Overwrite, "." + ArchiveFileExtension, "")

    If Right(unzipToPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        unzipToPath = unzipToPath + "\"
    End If
    
    tempUnzip_FolderPath = unzipToPath + "tempUnzip\"
    
    If Len(Dir(tempUnzip_FolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then           'if folder doesn't exist already
        MkDir tempUnzip_FolderPath
    End If
    
   
    ShellApp.Namespace(tempUnzip_FolderPath).CopyHere ShellApp.Namespace(zippedFileFullName).Items      'by A-Z it goes file by file doing an Extact to a specific folder called "tempUnzip"
    
    
    'Loop through the new tempUnzip_FolderPath and if file is in the original folder then delete it
    Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set MySource = objFSO.GetFolder(tempUnzip_FolderPath)
    Set MySourceFiles = MySource.Files
    
    For Each File In MySourceFiles        'For Each File In mySource.SubFolders
        
        UnzippedFile_LastOccuranceofPoint = InStrRev(File.Name, ".")
        UnzippedFile_FileExtension = Right(File.Name, Len(File.Name) - UnzippedFile_LastOccuranceofPoint)
        
        If Overwrite = "Yes" Then
            If FileExists(unzipToPath + File.Name) Then
                Kill unzipToPath + File.Name
                Name File.path As unzipToPath + File.Name
            End If
        
        ElseIf Overwrite = "Ask" Then
            ShellApp.Namespace(unzipToPath).CopyHere ShellApp.Namespace(zippedFileFullName).Items
            Name File.path As unzipToPath + File.Name
        Else
            OLD_NAME = File.path
            NEW_NAME = unzipToPath & ArchiveFileNoExtension & "." & UnzippedFile_FileExtension
            
            If FileExists(NEW_NAME) Then
                Kill NEW_NAME
            End If
            
            Name OLD_NAME As NEW_NAME
            
        End If

        
    Next File

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
        Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        
        If Right(tempUnzip_FolderPath, 1) = "\" Then
            tempUnzip_FolderPath_Delete = Left(tempUnzip_FolderPath, Len(tempUnzip_FolderPath) - 1)
        Else
            tempUnzip_FolderPath_Delete = tempUnzip_FolderPath
        End If
        
        FSO.DeleteFolder tempUnzip_FolderPath_Delete, False

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer myself that worked, thought it might help someone else.

I added these instead of the lines in my code and it did the job:

```
'Copy the files & folders from the zip into a folder
On Error Resume Next
Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

'Check if ShellApp is initialized before using it
If ShellApp Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Error creating Shell Application. Unable to proceed.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If
```